# Card/Tile Game, loops dont update element0 of playerHand properly

Tags: unity, c#, logic

**The Problem**

I am dealing from another class and into a player's Tray(A class with a List of Tiles and an array of bools to show that a slot in the tray is full).  When dealing into the player's tray, I update the list and bool array after each tile.  The first element of the bool array never gets filled, and I think its a logic error with my loops.
*I am looking for suggestions about how to make sure that the first element of the bool array gets populated after updating each tile.*

The image shows what happens to the bool array in the inspector when one tile is dealt.  The second part of the image is when the second card is dealt.

**BackGround**

In Unity 2D:
I have a *Tile* class, *PlayerTileTray* class, *PlayerTileTrayManager* class and a *TileManager* class.

*TileManager* creates a List and adds elements to the list, setting the *Tile* variables.
*TileManager* has a Deal Method with an OnTileSent(Tile sentTile) event that sends the top tile as a parameter.

*PlayerTileTrayManager* listens to the event using the OnTileSent Method.
*PlayerTileTrayManager*'s job is to take that tileSent and place it in one of several _trays in a PlaceTileInFirstEmptySlotOfTrays method.
I am currently using an array of trays called _tray[].

If an next element of the _tray array is null, I Instantiate a gameObject Prefab representing the tray and add a *PlayerTileTray* instance to the prefab as _tray[trayIndex].

The *PlayerTileTray* has an array of bools,slotFull[], to show whether a slot is full.
In the *PlayerTileTrayManager*: I loop through _tray and then slots of that tray to call the UpdateTrayWithTile method of *PlayerTileTray* UpdateTrayWiltTile adds the tile to a List in _tray, then trys to update the _tray bool variables emptyTray, fullTray and slotFull[].

**The main problem I am having**
I am currently using a nested for loop.  I have tried do while loops.
The first bool element slotFull[0] never gets set to true despite how I try to make it true.  When the first tile is dealt, slotFull[0] stays false.  When the second tile is dealt both slotFull[0] and slotFull[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WfyY.jpg) are true;

The results of everything else is achieved or will be if I can fix the first element
of slotFull updating properly..

[image]
**TileManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TileManager :MonoBehaviour
{   
    //For testing
    private int _topTile = 0;
    private List<Tile> _fullStackTiles = new List<Tile>();
    private static int _stockTileCount = 16;
    private static int _numberOfTileSets = 4;

    public int tilesToDeal = 1;
    public static Dictionary <string,Tile> stockTiles = new Dictionary <string,Tile>();
    public static List<Tile> shuffledTiles = new List<Tile>() ;
    public static int maxTiles = _numberOfTileSets * _stockTileCount;

    / **Singleton Stuff and Delegate,Event and Publisher Method removed for Brevity */
    void Awake(){
        _instance = this;  //  <--Singleton
    }
    void Start(){
        AssignTiles ();
        createFullStackWithSetOf(_numberOfTileSets);
        shuffledTiles = _fullStackTiles;

        //Shuffle is located in MyExtensions
        shuffledTiles.Shuffle();
    }
    void AssignTiles(){/* Method Contents removed for Brevity */ }

    void createFullStackWithSetOf(int numSets){
        //Create a stack of tiles with _numOfTileSets of stockTiles
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,Tile> t in stockTiles){
            for(int i = 0; i < numSets; i++)
                _fullStackTiles.Add(t.Value);
        }
    }
    public void Deal(int numIilesToDeal){
        for(int i = 0; i < numIilesToDeal; i++){
            //TileSend method is near the beginning of this script in the Delegate #region
            //TileSend (shuffledTiles[_topTile]);
            OnTileSent(shuffledTiles[_topTile]);
            shuffledTiles.RemoveAt(_topTile);

            //create node for instantiated tile
            //insert tile into Node
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerTileTrayManager**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerTileTrayManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static int _maxNumberOfTrays = TileManager.maxTiles / PlayerTileTray.trayMax;
    private List<Tile> _playerTiles = new List<Tile>();
    private GameObject _tilePrefab;
    private PlayerTileTray[] _tray = new PlayerTileTray[8];

    public Tile tileFromDraw;
    public GameObject TrayPrefab;
    List <GameObject> _trayObject  = new List<GameObject>();

    void OnEnable(){
        TileManager.Instance.TileSent += OnTileSent;
    }
    void OnDisable(){
        TileManager.Instance.TileSent -= OnTileSent;
    }

    void OnTileSent(object source, Tile tileSent){
        _playerTiles.Add (tileSent);
        PlaceTileInFirstEmptySlotOfTrays (tileSent);

        GameObject go = PrefabMap.Instance.GetValueByKey(tileSent.tileName);
        Instantiate (go,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);

        //move _tilePrefab to childLocation
    }
    void PlaceTileInFirstEmptySlotOfTrays(Tile placeTile)
    {
        for(int trayIndex = 0;trayIndex < _maxNumberOfTrays;trayIndex++){
            //for(int slotIndex = 0; slotIndex < PlayerTileTray.trayMax; slotIndex ++)
            int slotIndex = 0;
            do{
                if(_tray[trayIndex] == null)
                {
                    _trayObject.Add (Instantiate (TrayPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject);
                    _tray[trayIndex] = _trayObject[trayIndex].GetComponent<PlayerTileTray>();
                }
                if (!_tray[trayIndex].fullTray)
                {
                    if(!_tray[trayIndex].fullSlot[slotIndex])
                    {
                        _tray[trayIndex].UpdateTrayWithTile(placeTile);
                        Debug.Log (placeTile.tileName + "was placed in the " + trayIndex + " trayIndex iteration and in the " + 
                                   slotIndex + " slotIndex iteration.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                slotIndex++;
            }while(slotIndex < PlayerTileTray.trayMax);
        }
    }
    public void showHand(){/* Not relevant to the Question*/    }
    //CycleTrays
}
```

**PlayerTileTray.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class PlayerTileTray :MonoBehaviour{

    public static int trayMax = 8;

    public bool[] fullSlot;
    public bool fullTray;
    public bool emptyTray;

    public Tile tileFromTrayManager;
    public List<Tile> tilesInTray = new List<Tile>();

    public PlayerTileTray(){
        fullSlot = new bool[trayMax];
        fullTray = false;
        emptyTray = true;
    }
    void Start(){
        for(int i = 0; i < trayMax; i++)
            fullSlot[i] = false;
    }
    public void UpdateTrayWithTile(Tile tileToTray){
        tilesInTray.Add (tileToTray);
        for (int i = 0; i < tilesInTray.Count; i++)
            fullSlot[i] = true;
        if(tilesInTray.Count >= 0)
            emptyTray = false;
        if(tilesInTray.Count >= 8)
            fullTray = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never clearly state what your problem is. I mean, this sentence sounds like it might be the problem you are wanting help with, but it's so buried that it's hard to tell: "The first bool element slotFull[0] never gets set to true despite how I try to make it true." You really should open your lengthy question with a clear statement of what you are asking. The details of your code architecture are nice to know but only relevant *after* we know what we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the top of my post.  In trying to get all the information out there, I failed to make a clear point.

Answer (score 1):

In the PlayerTileTray, I initaized my Boolean array in Start().  I changed this to Awake and code worked as expected.